# Codeigniter form_validation birthdate

Tags: php, codeigniter, date

I have this html:(ill also add my gender part and ask if its correct)

```
<?php $form_error = $this->session->flashdata('error'); ?>    
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="gender">Gender</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="gender" name="gender">
            <option disabled selected value="">select a gender</option>
            <option value="Male">Male</option>
            <option value="Female">Female</option>
            <option value="Other">Other</option>
        </select>
      <div id="form_error"><?php echo $form_error('gender'); ?></div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="birthdate">Birthdate</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="birthdate" name="birthdate" type="date">
        <div id="form_error"><?php echo $form_error['birthdate']; ?></div>
      </div>
```

and in my account controller:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|is_unique[users.username]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|min_length[8]|max_length[20]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('confirm_password', 'Confirm Password', 'trim|required|matches[password]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('gender', 'Gender', 'trim|required|in_list[Male,Female,Other]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('birthdate', 'Birthdate', 'trim|required');


if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
    $form_error = array('username' => form_error('username'),
            'password' => form_error('password'),
            'confirm_password' => form_error('confirm_password'),
            'gender' => form_error('gender'),
            'birthdate' => form_error('birthdate'));
    $this->session->set_flashdata('error', $form_error);
    redirect('pages/register_user');
```

Pages controller:

```
public function register_user(){
$data['title'] = 'Register';
$this->load->view('template/header',$data);
$this->load->view('template/navbar');
$this->load->view('pages/registration');
$this->load->view('template/footer');
}
```

My question is, what do i put it the rules for birthdate? I just echoed out the value that is taken from it via `$this->input->post('birthdate');`and the value is like this "YYYY-MM-DD"

The good thing about is that it's already in the syntax that phpmyadmin date accepts but i don't know how to validate this date since in the codeigniter userguide for form validation in the rules reference are

numeric - but the value contains dash.
Alpha_dash - but it assumes value is alpha numeric which is not.

I tried the matches rule but idk how to set it to match the syntax not the value like: matches[YYYY-MM-DD]

Comment: So you want to check if the [given birthdate] format would be in this format : Y-m-d (e.g 2018-01-01)?

Comment: Yes, although there's no way to select any other format since i've used html input type date but still i want to validate it.

Comment: If you want to reformat it `$new_birthday = date("YYY-MM-DD", strtotime($birthday))`

Comment: if you are using bootstrap, then use bootstrap datepicker. here is the reference url check it https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

this will automatically validate your date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to set a callback method in your rules. This callback method is where your validation logic is performed.

See the CodeIgniter Reference for Validation Callbacks [Here](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks-your-own-validation-methods)

Something like this to call a method 'example_method'

```
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('birthdate', 'Birthdate', 'trim|required','callback_example_method');
```

Then, I don't know what you want to do as far as validating input. If you want to convert the string to a date, or see if the input can become a valid date, checkout php strtotime(). This example just validates that the input string can be converted into some sort of date.

```
        public function example_method($birthday)
        {
            // Check string is valid date

            $birthday = date("YYY-MM-DD", strtotime($birthday)) 

            if ($birthday)
            {

                    return TRUE;
            }
            else
            {
                    return FALSE;
            }
        }
```

Comment: The if($time AND $birthday) statement, does it compare if both are true? I've been coding php for idk how long but i never really read the manual in detail so i took it for granted and now im confused. 

Say for example:
$result = $this->db->insert('table',$data); say the insert is successful
if($result) in this part, does it assume that $result is true?

Comment: The example is rather thrown together. The strtotime() method returns false if it fails, as does the date() method. The so the if statement just checks that the string has been converted to a date without a mishap. If you wanted to then use that date to compare it with another date, say, for age verification, you can expand on the example.

Comment: I modified my answer based on comments to your original question, now the method reformats your date as you'd like it to look, and returns false if it cant do so.

Comment: Would it work the same if,

if(date("YYYY-MM-DD",strtotime($birthday))){ }

Comment: Yep, it would work fine. The reason I set it to birthday like that was just for readability. This way would work too because the date would return false if the method failed, and then your validation method would also return false.

Comment: Calling the callback function, I've read the userguide but the 4th parameter is for custom error message.

Should it be:

$this->form_validation->set_rules('birthdate', 'Birthdate', 'trim|required|callback_example_method');